Tomcat cannot connect to mysql database
I have a web application that has an admin login page.
When i try to login to the admin page i get this error message:
Type Exception Report

Message Unable to compile class for JSP:

Description The server encountered an unexpected condition that prevented it from fulfilling the request.

Exception

org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to compile class for JSP: 

An error occurred at line: [13] in the jsp file: [/adminlogact.jsp]
databasecon cannot be resolved
10:        
11:        // String user=null;
12:         //String password=null;
13:     Connection con=databasecon.getconnection();
14:         Statement st = con.createStatement();
15:         ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("select * from admin where user='"+username+"' and pwd='"+password+"'");
16:        if(rs.next())


Stacktrace:
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.javacError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:102)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.javacError(ErrorDispatcher.java:214)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.JDTCompiler.generateClass(JDTCompiler.java:531)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:398)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:368)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:352)
    org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:603)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:399)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:379)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:327)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:623)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51)
Note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the server logs.

here is the admin page code:
<%@page import="java.sql.*"%>
<%@page import="databaseconnection.*"%>
<%@ page session="true" %>
<%
    String username = request.getParameter("username");
    System.out.println(username);
    String password = request.getParameter("password");
    System.out.println(password);
    try{
       
       // String user=null;
        //String password=null;
    Connection con=databasecon.getconnection();
        Statement st = con.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("select * from admin where user='"+username+"' and pwd='"+password+"'");
       if(rs.next())
        {
         String  user = rs.getString(2);
           session.setAttribute("user",user);
           System.out.println("User:"+user);
            response.sendRedirect("adminhome.jsp");
        }
       else 
        {
            response.sendRedirect("admin.html?m1=LoginFail");
                }
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println("Error in adminlogact"+e.getMessage());
    }
%>

here is the databasecon java code:
package databaseconnection;
import java.sql.*;

public class databasecon
{
static Connection co;
public static Connection getconnection()
{


    try
    {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
        co = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test","root","mypass");


    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println("Database Error"+e);
    }
    return co;
}

}
I am able to login tot he database and view the tables just fine but seems tomcat cannot find the database.
The catalina log dosent have any errors
directory structure:
C:\PROGRAMDATA\TOMCAT9
├───conf
│   └───Catalina
│       └───localhost
├───logs
├───temp
├───webapps
│   ├───docs
│   │   ├───annotationapi
│   │   ├───api
│   │   ├───appdev
│   │   │   └───sample
│   │   │       ├───docs
│   │   │       ├───src
│   │   │       │   └───mypackage
│   │   │       └───web
│   │   │           ├───images
│   │   │           └───WEB-INF
│   │   ├───architecture
│   │   │   ├───requestProcess
│   │   │   └───startup
│   │   ├───config
│   │   ├───elapi
│   │   ├───images
│   │   │   └───fonts
│   │   ├───jaspicapi
│   │   ├───jspapi
│   │   ├───META-INF
│   │   ├───servletapi
│   │   ├───tribes
│   │   ├───WEB-INF
│   │   │   └───jsp
│   │   └───websocketapi
│   ├───examples
│   │   ├───jsp
│   │   │   ├───async
│   │   │   ├───cal
│   │   │   ├───checkbox
│   │   │   ├───colors
│   │   │   ├───dates
│   │   │   ├───error
│   │   │   ├───forward
│   │   │   ├───images
│   │   │   ├───include
│   │   │   ├───jsp2
│   │   │   │   ├───el
│   │   │   │   ├───jspattribute
│   │   │   │   ├───jspx
│   │   │   │   ├───misc
│   │   │   │   ├───simpletag
│   │   │   │   └───tagfiles
│   │   │   ├───jsptoserv
│   │   │   ├───num
│   │   │   ├───security
│   │   │   │   └───protected
│   │   │   ├───sessions
│   │   │   ├───simpletag
│   │   │   ├───snp
│   │   │   ├───tagplugin
│   │   │   └───xml
│   │   ├───META-INF
│   │   ├───servlets
│   │   │   ├───images
│   │   │   └───nonblocking
│   │   ├───WEB-INF
│   │   │   ├───classes
│   │   │   │   ├───async
│   │   │   │   ├───cal
│   │   │   │   ├───checkbox
│   │   │   │   ├───colors
│   │   │   │   ├───compressionFilters
│   │   │   │   ├───dates
│   │   │   │   ├───error
│   │   │   │   ├───examples
│   │   │   │   ├───filters
│   │   │   │   ├───http2
│   │   │   │   ├───jsp2
│   │   │   │   │   └───examples
│   │   │   │   │       ├───el
│   │   │   │   │       └───simpletag
│   │   │   │   ├───listeners
│   │   │   │   ├───nonblocking
│   │   │   │   ├───num
│   │   │   │   ├───sessions
│   │   │   │   ├───trailers
│   │   │   │   ├───util
│   │   │   │   ├───validators
│   │   │   │   └───websocket
│   │   │   │       ├───chat
│   │   │   │       ├───drawboard
│   │   │   │       │   └───wsmessages
│   │   │   │       ├───echo
│   │   │   │       └───snake
│   │   │   ├───jsp
│   │   │   ├───lib
│   │   │   └───tags
│   │   └───websocket
│   ├───Feedback_Analysis
│   │   ├───images
│   │   ├───META-INF
│   │   └───WEB-INF
│   │       ├───classes
│   │       │   ├───conf
│   │       │   └───java
│   │       │       ├───databaseconnection
│   │       │       └───opt
│   │       │           └───databse
│   │       │               └───conn
│   │       └───lib

the webapp is Feedback_Analysis

This is compilation issue, not a connection issue.  It's unclear what your directory structure is but the class databasecon will not be automatically compiled as it's not a JSP.  As a side note, if this code will be used anywhere but for your own learning it is not secure and it organized poorly.  Can you share the directory structure of your project?

thx for replying...yes it is only for learning. i will edit the question with the directory structure

posted directory structure

That looks wrong. You have a 'package' before databaseconnection and that 'package' is called java

thanks to @stdunbar for pointing me int he right direction.
I manually compiled the java class databaseconnection using "javac" and placed the databaseconnection.class file in place of the databaseconnection.java file and that resolved the issue.
